# Creating Real A4 Pages in React

Tags: reactjs

So, I'm trying to achieve a view that looks like an `A4`, but the problem is that when I have so much content the view height changes, and then it is no anymore an `A4`.

I want to find a solution, to break the pages, for example, when `height: 200px` is filled with content, text, or image or whatever, to skip and add another div with `200px` height, and so on, to continue, in a type of form to create pages of pdf.

Comment: do you use print css rules ? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm

Comment: @Robert, to generic, can you share an mini example and stuff.

Comment: This is minimal expample... i suggest starting learnig programin from somting easier to adopt. There is planty of examples but you need to have basic knowledge from algorithmic/programming to understand it. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23206/Sudoku-Algorithm-Generates-a-Valid-Sudoku-in-0-018